# C# using to create a quiz no ERRORS BUT Index out of range exception was unhandled

Tags: c#

I'm creating quiz program using 3 radio buttons and one text box but it is not working..

I tried to solve but can't, pls help me.

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string[,] Quest = new string[10, 4];
    string[,] Ans = new string[10, 2]; // in this array error was raising

    int i = -1;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Quest[0, 0] = "Which one of these stores more data than a DVD ?  ";
        Quest[0, 1] = "CD Rom ";
        Quest[0, 2] = "Floppy";
        Quest[0, 3] = "Blue Ray Disk  ";
        Quest[1, 0] = "Eight Bits make up a ";
        Quest[1, 1] = "byte ";
        Quest[1, 2] = "megabyte";
        Quest[1, 3] = "kilobyte  ";
        Quest[2, 0] = "The printed output from a computer is called  ";
        Quest[2, 1] = "Copy  ";
        Quest[2, 2] = "Soft Copy ";
        Quest[2, 3] = "Hard Copy  ";
        Quest[3, 0] = "Which one of these also known as read/write memory ?  ";
        Quest[3, 1] = "ROM";
        Quest[3, 2] = "RAM";
        Quest[3, 3] = "DVD  ";
        Quest[4, 0] = "To apply center alignment to a paragraph we can press  ";
        Quest[4, 1] = "Ctrl + S ";
        Quest[4, 2] = "Ctrl + C ";
        Quest[4, 3] = "Ctrl + E ";
        Quest[5, 0] = "We can insert a page number at  ";
        Quest[5, 1] = "Header ";
        Quest[5, 2] = "Footer ";
        Quest[5, 3] = "Both A and B ";
        Quest[6, 0] = "Which one can be used as watermark in a word document";
        Quest[6, 1] = "Text";
        Quest[6, 2] = "Image";
        Quest[6, 3] = "Both A and B ";
        Quest[7, 0] = "HTML is used to create ";
        Quest[7, 1] = "machine language program ";
        Quest[7, 2] = "high level program ";
        Quest[7, 3] = "web page ";
        Quest[8, 0] = "The computer jargon - WWWW, stands for : ";
        Quest[8, 1] = "World Wide Web Worm ";
        Quest[8, 2] = "World Wide Wildlife Web ";
        Quest[8, 3] = "World Wide Women's Week";
        Quest[9, 0] = "Which one of the following is not a search engine?  ";
        Quest[9, 1] = "Bing ";
        Quest[9, 2] = "Google ";
        Quest[9, 3] = "Windows";
        Ans[0, 0] = "Blue Ray Disk  ";
        Ans[1, 0] = "byte ";
        Ans[2, 0] = "Hard Copy  ";
        Ans[3, 0] = "RAM";
        Ans[4, 0] = "Ctrl + E ";
        Ans[5, 0] = "Both A and B ";
        Ans[6, 0] = "Both A and B ";
        Ans[7, 0] = "web page ";
        Ans[8, 0] = "World Wide Web Worm ";
        Ans[9, 0] = "Windows";
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        if (i == 9)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            radioButton1.Checked = false;
            radioButton2.Checked = false;
            radioButton3.Checked = false;
            textBox1.Text = Quest[i, 0];
            radioButton1.Text = Quest[i, 1];
            radioButton2.Text = Quest[i, 2];
            radioButton3.Text = Quest[i, 3];
         }
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ans[i, 1] = radioButton1.Text;
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ans[i, 1] = radioButton2.Text;
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ans[i, 1] = radioButton3.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int j;
        int count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (Ans[j, 0] == Ans[j, 1])
                count += 1;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("You have shocred" + count + " marks");
    }
}
```

The exception that is caught in code is:

> Index out of range exception

It is caught on **Ans** array.

I'm creating quiz program using 3 radio buttons and one text box but it is not working..

Comment: You need to describe your error in detail - exactly where & when did the error occur. Have you tried using the debugger yourself - put a break point on the line where the error occurs & look at the array index values when you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Are you sure your data is initialized when first timer fires up?

Comment: @MarkBenovsky: or possibly a radiobutton change event before the first timer tick.

Comment: @PaulF yeah, and probably **i** is -1 as he assigned it `int i = -1;`

Comment: Ans[i, 1] = radioButton1.Text; // here the exception (error)comes @mr.PauLF

Comment: @m.rogalski. yes, i initialized data..

Comment: in VB.net there is no problem the program running properly.

Comment: read previous comments, guys that posted 2 comments before you just gave you an answer...